# What is the True Pinout and Function of the 74ls181 in both of its modes (Active High and Active Low)?

Tags: digital-logic, ttl, alu

I've found several datasheets for the 74ls181 with pinout and function diagrams as pictured below.

This from Jameco (where I bought mine): https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/46973.pdf

[image]

[image]

This one as the first google search result: http://www.esi.uclm.es/www/isanchez/apuntes/ci/74181.pdf

[image]

These do not at all agree with each other. What happens to P and G when switching modes? What happens to the outputs when switching modes? Do they invert or not? How does one go about sorting out this mess?

Comment: Can you circle the discrepancies?

Comment: inverted outputs, inverted P and/or G?

Answer (score 2):

Polarity of operands is a sort of arbitrary thing, a matter of data interpretation. What the different symbols mean is that if the data are treated as "active LOW", then the propagate signals also must be treated as "active LOW", and vice versa.

From the datasheet, page 5-2:

> As indicated, the LS181 can be used with either active LOW inputs 
>   producing active LOW outputs or with active HIGH inputs 
>   producing active HIGH outputs.

How does one go about sorting out this mess? This circuit was probably used last time about 30 years ago. The mess is usually sorted out by implementing a clean implementation of the ALU in FPGA using clear Verilog altogether with all control circuitry, pipelines, caches, microcode, and peripheral ports, all in chip much smaller than the LS181 itself.

Comment: P&G are always active 0 and not affected by Mode =0,1 complement for functions

Comment: what about F. Do the outputs invert or not?

Comment: I'm more concerned with the outputs and the function of P and G under each circumstance. I understand that this change is only a matter of interpretation with regard to inputs.

Comment: @RobertMeade, if you really want to use this dinosaur of electronics, get some circuit simulator with proper library for SN74 chips, write a test bench, and figure out the exact behavior.

Comment: i'll probably have to do just that. Good idea

Comment: Looking at the logic diagram an truth table , yes F is complemented by M

Comment: it is in the first logic diagram and truth table, but not in the 2nd? Is your answer based off of analysis of the gates or of what I've included in the post?

Comment: No my answer is based on the truth table and schematic and the data sheet

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of getting extra functions out of the device.

What they're saying is, the ALU can be used with active-high or active-low data, but to do that you have to re-map the functions as shown in the tables. For example, the active-high AND operation (F = 4'b10011) becomes an active-low OR by DeMorgan's Theorem.

So if you need a function that isn't provided in the active high set but is in the active-low, you can NOT your data and use the active-low opcode. You could do this by adding a NOT control to the input and output prior to and after the ALU for example and have your microcode flip the data as needed.

Or, you could use extra instructions to NOT input the data, do the op, then un-NOT it once it's finished. Slower, but takes less hardware.

Honestly though, I've never seen it used with active-low data. It's just too weird to wrap one's head around.

BONUS: Explanation of the 'LS181, with an interactive sim. Link: http://www.righto.com/2017/03/inside-vintage-74181-alu-chip-how-it.html